# Need to change str from sql query to currency

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

How can I get the productPrice below to show as $7.99 etc.? I've tried everything I can find. It is small money in db table. Thanks.

Protected Sub printMenuBlock(ByVal productName As String)
        'Set up variable storing the product and pull from databse 
        Dim product = ReadProduct(productName)

```
    'Add necessary markup to str variable, with products information within

    For i As Integer = 0 To product.Count - 1

        str += "<div class='menuItem'>"
        'str += "    <img alt='Item Picture' class='itemPicture' src='" + product(i).ImagePath.Substring(3).Replace("\", "/") + "' />"
        str += "    <div class='itemInfo'>"
        str += "        <h1 class='itemName'>"
        str += "            " + product(i).Item("ProductName") + "</h1>"
        'str += "        <h3 class='itemDescription'>"
        str += "            " + product(i).Item("ProductDescription")
        str += "        <h1 class ='itemPrice'>"
        str += "            " + String.Format("{0:C}", product(i).Item("ProductPrice")) + "</h1>"
        str += "        "
        str += "        </div>"

        str += "    </div>"

    Next
```

This is code from interaction class:

Public Class Interaction
    ' New instance of the Sql command object
    Private cmdSelect As New SqlCommand
    ' Instance of the Connection class
    Private conIn As New Connection

## Region "Menu functions and subs"

```
' Set up the SQL statement for finding a Product by ProductCat
Private Sub GetProduct(ByVal CatIn As String)
    ' SQL String

    Dim strSelect As String
    strSelect = "SELECT *  "
    strSelect &= " FROM Menu "
    'strSelect &= " WHERE ProductCat = @CatIn"
    strSelect &= "ORDER BY 'ProductCat'"
    ' Set up the connection to the datebase
    cmdSelect.Connection = conIn.Connect
    ' Add the SQL string to the connection
    cmdSelect.CommandText = strSelect
    ' Add the parameters to the connection
    cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@CatIn", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CatIn
End Sub



'Function to create list of rows and columns
Public Function ReadProduct(ByVal CatIn As String) As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    'Declare variable to hold list
    Dim ReturnProducts As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Try
        Call GetProduct(CatIn)
        Dim dbr As SqlDataReader
        ' Execute the created SQL command from GetProduct and set to the SqlDataReader object
        dbr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader
        'Get number of columns in current row
        Dim FieldCount = dbr.FieldCount()
        Dim ColumnList As New List(Of String)
        'Loop through all columns and add to list
        For i As Integer = 0 To FieldCount - 1
            ColumnList.Add(dbr.GetName(i))
        Next
        While dbr.Read()
            'Declare variable to hold list
            Dim ReturnProduct As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            'Loop through all rows and add to list
            For i As Integer = 0 To FieldCount - 1
                ReturnProduct.Add(ColumnList(i), dbr.GetValue(i).ToString())
            Next
            'Add to final list
            ReturnProducts.Add(ReturnProduct)
        End While
        cmdSelect.Parameters.Clear()
        'Close connection
        dbr.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Dim strOut As String
        strOut = ex.Message
        Console.WriteLine(strOut)
    End Try
    ' Return the Product object
    Return ReturnProducts
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
+ String.Format("{0:C}", product(i).Item("ProductPrice")) +
```

P.S. You may want to use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b.aspx) for these kinds of constructs.

Comment: No syntax errors but didn't do the trick. It still shows up as 7.9900. And I will def look into StringBuilder. Thanks.

Comment: @Lolo what kind of object is product - datatable?

Comment: I edited original so you could see the whole relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: Okay worked better that time. Sorry for my "newbieness". I appreciate your help.

Comment: Good job formatting the code. Ok, can you try if `product(i).Item("ProductPrice").ToString("C")` works?

Comment: I tried that and it says input string in incorrect format. I've searched the web and this is driving me crazy!! Seems like it should be easy!!

Comment: Are you sure the Item("ProductPrice") is not string already? I know it's money in the DB, but can u in debugger verify its type in code?

Comment: Okay it is string already. Still don't know how to change it to currency. However, that leads me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, you need to modify line ` ReturnProduct.Add(ColumnList(i), dbr.GetValue(i).ToString())` for this specific element. Use `.ToString("C")` here for product price

Comment: Yay!! You are my hero of the day!! Answer accepted!! Thanks!!